# Link array inside CSV for Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j

I have a file with 3 column where one of the column will consist of an "array" with delimiter as say "," . I will need to link the text inside the array to form something like a linked list. After which, it will be linked to the other 2 column.

For example:
Column 1 (Text): A
Column 2 (Array of text): B1, B2, B3, B4
Column 3 (Text): C

I will need something like A->B1->B2->B3->B4->C to be visualise in Neo4j.

I need help in forming the "LOAD CSV..." query. Appreciate any help offered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split for extracting each element of the desired array

`USING PERIODIC COMMIT`

`LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM`

`'file://directory/file.csv' AS line`

`with SPLIT(line.columnName,',') as arrayColumn`

now you can use each data of the arrayColumn like

`arrayColumn[0]`, `arrayColumn[1]`

then you can create relationships or node

`MERGE (v:LabelName {name:arrayColumn[0]})-[:relations]->(v:LabelName {name:arrayColumn[1]})`

Hope this helps ...